# Creating Excel File in Apex code

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

'm wondering is it possible to create Excel or CSV file in apex code (as attachment) is it possible ? currently i only see it works with VF page, but i'm looking to do it in apex code not using vf page, I don't see any options.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you plan to store the file if you don't want to do it with a VF page? Store it in a document or something?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no native CSV Library or API in Apex to handle the creation of CSV files. Certainly not XLS documents although you could use the native XML DOM libraries to create an Excel friendly XML document.

To write a CSV, this should be fairly simple; it's basically a big huge string with a carriage return and/or line feed at the close of each full record write. You'll need to carefully manage property value escapement by using `String.replaceAll('\','\'');` etc. Which in turn will chew up your script statements pretty badly.
Next, create a new `Document()`, convert your string to a Blob using `Blob.valueOf(String)` and instantiate that blob as the body of the Document.
If you are planning on writing a very large document, you may want to consider writing to some other format type or offloading this processing to a remote system (EC2?) and letting it respond with the Document in time.

I have some Apex CSV utilities already written if you need them.

Comment: I stumbled across this post, and with further googling, I found that salesforce now has a native escapeCsv() method: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/related/New+String+Methods